# MP movie controller removes when done button is clicked in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am playing video in MPmovieController it works fine but player removes when complete video is played.I want that when user pressed done button then video should stop here is the code i am using.

```
     NSURL*myURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url];
     MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:myURL];

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:moviePlayerController];

     [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
     [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
     [moviePlayerController play];

- (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification
     {
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self                           name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification                             object:moviePlayerController];
    [moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [moviePlayerController release];
       }
```

Comment: You're telling it to remove itself from its superview when the playback is over. Delete that line if you don't want it to go away.

Comment: i want that after play back it shoud go but also when user in between tap done then it should also remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    NSURL *fileURL=[NSURL URLWithString:[[array objectAtIndex:videoid] valueForKey:@"VideoUrl"]];
    self.mpPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.mpPlayer];
    [self.mpPlayer.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    self.mpPlayer.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=NO;
    [self.mpPlayer.moviePlayer play];



 - (void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
   {
      MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [notification object];
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:moviePlayer];
      [moviePlayer pause];
      [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
      // [moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
  }
```

may be it will help.

happy coding...

Comment: you are not getting what i am saying i want that after play back it shoud go but also when user in between tap done then it should also remove

Answer (score 0):

remove this line into your  then it will work

```
[moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: i want that after play back it shoud go but also when user in between tap done then it should also remove

Comment: removeFromSuperview when you want to user pressed back and use  [moviePlayer pause]; or[moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];  when done